# Algorithms with HMAC key generation

Tags: java, hmac

I found those examples for HMAC signature.

Password base key generation:

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(passowrd.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
```

Random key generation:

```
KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
Key key = gen.generateKey;
```

Generation HMAC Signature

```
string passowrd = "password";
string data = "data";
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(key);
byte[] signature = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Do the algorithms in `SecretKeySpec` or `KeyGenerator` and `Mac` need to be matched? I tried with different algorithms like below, but It works.

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec("pass".getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(key);
byte[] signature = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Also this code below works

```
KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
gen.init(keysize);
val key = gen.generateKey;
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(key);
byte[] signature = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

I'm not sure it proper way or not. Actually when I change the algorithm in `KeyGenerator` it returns different length of key, but I think it's same if I specify key size as `init(int keysize)`. What if it's same what's the difference between using `SecureRandom`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JCA reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Mac), this is a peculiarity of the implementations of certain HMACs.

> With some MAC algorithms, the (secret-)key algorithm associated with the (secret-)key object used to initialize the Mac object does not matter (this is the case with the HMAC-MD5 and HMAC-SHA1 implementations of the SunJCE provider). With others, however, the (secret-)key algorithm does matter, and an InvalidKeyException is thrown if a (secret-)key object with an inappropriate (secret-)key algorithm is used.

As to why, I can't say. I can only guess that with [SecretKeySpec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html) changing the algorithm doesn't matter because:

> This class is only useful for raw secret keys that can be represented as a byte array and **have no key parameters associated with them**, e.g., DES or Triple DES keys.